# Reload page on URL change in AJAX filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating the AJAX filter. When any checkbox value checked then I am appending variable in URL.

```
window.history.pushState('null', 'null', newurl);
```

Variables are appending correctly but when I am pressing back button in the browser then it is writing the previous link in the search bar. I want to capture the event of link change. My main concern has reloaded the page when URL change.

Comment: Store values in session and redirect the page with values from sesssion

Comment: So why are you not listening for `popstate`?

Comment: @epascarello I want to detect URL change event so when URL change occurs then I need to reload page on that URL

Comment: Did you look at what popstate does?

Comment: I checked that but it does not work.

Comment: Than my app would fail if it did not work. When the url changes, it should be fired. You can than use the data to that call to rerun your search.